# Backpropagation intuitive problem

Tags: neural-networks

I was asked to backpropagate neural net following:

[image]

where $f$ stands for sigmoid function i.e. $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + exp(-x)}$ and $x_1 = (1, 2)$ and $y = (1, -1)$.

**My intuitive problem**

My question is how is this possible that we can calulate backpropagation whereas I don't know how $y_1$ was obtained? i.e. there is no function provided how $y_1 = 1$ was received. How can I for example calculate how big impact node with $f(x)$ has on $y$ whereas I don't know how $y$ how obtained? Am I thinking correctly, or I'm missing something and we really can tell it somehow?

Comment: To calculate "how big impact node with $f(x)$ has on $y$" you only need to know how $f(x)$ depends on $y$, not where $y$ came from. If I understand correctly, $f(x)$ is actually sigmoid applied to  the components of $0.5 x_1 + 0.5y$. If you know that, you should be able to calculate the impact on $y$.

Comment: Hmm okay...I understand that it can be done but I'm not sure how can I do it. $f(x)$ is a sigmoid function applied to $0.5x_1 + 0.5 \cdot 1$ where $1$ corresponds to bias. In our case node with $f(x)$ takes value $f(1) = 0.73$. Could you please tell me now how can I backpropagate through the nodes?

Comment: I misunderstood the problem. To calculate back-propagation you need a single value as your output layer (that is, your cost function). If you have a vector as output (and no target direction), then I'm not sure.